# Creating a contact with multiple phone numbers with php-ews

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I am trying to add multiple phone numbers to a contact that I am creating with Php-Ews. There is no documentation on adding multiple numbers to a contact. Can someone help me find out how to accomplish this?

here is what I have:

```
    // create a phone number
    $phone = new Type\PhoneNumberDictionaryEntryType();
    $phone->Key = new Type\PhoneNumberKeyType();
    $phone->Key->_ = Type\PhoneNumberKeyType::HOME_PHONE;
    $phone->_ = $info['phone'];

    // create a phone number
    $phone2 = new Type\PhoneNumberDictionaryEntryType();
    $phone2->Key = new Type\PhoneNumberKeyType();
    $phone2->Key->_ = Type\PhoneNumberKeyType::COMPANY_MAIN_PHONE;
    $phone2->_ = $info['phone'];

    // set the phone number
    $contact->PhoneNumbers = new Type\PhoneNumberDictionaryType();
    $contact->PhoneNumbers->Entry[] = $phone;
    $contact->PhoneNumbers->Entry[] = $phone2;
```

It looked to me like the `Entry[]` is an array. Therefore I thought I would be able to add as many as I would like as seen above. However when I do this I get the `The request failed schema validation: The required attribute 'Key' is missing.` error. I figured I had to add a key to the `[]` but I was unable to find out what that is.

Comment: Just a wild guess: did you try naming the entries? ->Entry['Mobile'] = $phone;

Comment: Yes i did. I added ['HOME'] and any variation. I even tried adding the keys that were a part of each phone number and that still gave the same error

Answer (score 0):

i never worked with php-ews but i hope i found your answer: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee159497(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee159497%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

those are the 'keys' you can use for the phonenumbers. found it on this page: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202532(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202532%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I needed. All that the `Entry[]` needed was an index starting at 0. So I added the below and it worked! Thanks for all the help!

```
    $phone = new Type\PhoneNumberDictionaryEntryType();
    $phone->Key = new Type\PhoneNumberKeyType();
    $phone->Key->_ = Type\PhoneNumberKeyType::HOME_PHONE;
    $phone->_ = $info['phone'];

    // create a phone number
    $phone2 = new Type\PhoneNumberDictionaryEntryType();
    $phone2->Key = new Type\PhoneNumberKeyType();
    $phone2->Key->_ = Type\PhoneNumberKeyType::COMPANY_MAIN_PHONE;
    $phone2->_ = $info['phone'];

    // set the phone number
    $contact->PhoneNumbers = new Type\PhoneNumberDictionaryType();
    $contact->PhoneNumbers->Entry[0] = $phone;
    $contact->PhoneNumbers->Entry[1] = $phone2;
```